# Flutter: Convert firestore snapshot to list in streambuilder

Tags: list, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need to convert a snapshot from cloud firestore to a list, i know this is unnecessary to show the data but i need it to reorder the data based in other parameters, this is my code

```
 Stream chatRooms;
  List item = [];

 Widget chatRoomsList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: chatRooms,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData &&
            !snapshot.hasError) {
          item = [];

          item = snapshot.data;

          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: item.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ChatRoomsTile(
                  otherUserUid:item[index]['arrayUsers']
                      .replaceAll("[", "")
                      .replaceAll(widget.user.uid, "")
                      .replaceAll("]", "")
                      .replaceAll(",", "")
                      .replaceAll(" ", ""),
                  chatRoomId:
                  item[index]["chatRoomId"],
                  user: widget.user,
                );
              });
        } else
            return Container();
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getUserInfogetChats();
    super.initState();
  }

  getUserInfogetChats() async {
    DatabaseMethods().getUserChats(widget.user.uid).then((snapshots) {
      setState(() {
        chatRooms = snapshots;
      });
    });
  }
```

and im getting this error

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building StreamBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<dynamic, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>>#48820):
type 'QuerySnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
```

Comment: on which line do u get the error

Comment: @PeterHaddad in this line:           item = snapshot.data;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
item = snapshot.data;
```

into this:

```
item = snapshot.data.documents;
```

`documents` should return a `List<DocumentSnapshot>`, so also change the type of `item`:

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> item = [];
```